# Restart or cancel input() [Python]

Tags: python, function, sockets, connection, messaging

I want to restart the `input('CLIENT >> ')` when the client recieves a message from the server and the same for the server (the server and client being python scripts in this case)
client.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345

print('Connecting to ', host, port)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
  msg = input('CLIENT >> ')
  s.send(msg.encode())
  msg = str(s.recv(1024))
  print('SERVER >> ', str(msg))
```

server.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = ''
port = 12345

print('Server started!')
print('Waiting for clients...')

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('Got connection from', addr)

while True:
    recieved = c.recv(1024)
    print('\n', addr, ' >> ', str(recieved))
    msg = input('SERVER >> ')
    c.send(msg.encode())
```

NOTES:

- Using my laptop to run both of these scripts, I don't have an actual server in real life
- Python Version: 3.8
- OS: Windows 10
- Editor: PyCharm Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what restarting input means...
If you mean to show messages while 'writing messages' in the input then consider learning about threads, and spin off a thread to get messages from the server/client and print to the screen.

Comment: I mean to rewrite the prompt

Comment: I know that I'd have to use threads for this but I don't know how

Comment: @Dur Topolanski please do comments in comment section not in answer section.

Comment: @CrabbyFish You should import the threads module and its quite friendly and easy references : https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ , https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html